# how to append the last row of one pandas datafram to another

Tags: pandas, dataframe, append, row, stock

So basically i am iteratively generating a dataframe and after each iteration i want to take the final row of the dataframe and store it in a separate dataframe to be used for future calculations. i have tried the following:

`Storage_Df = Storage_Df.append(Iterating_Df.iloc[-1], ignore_index = True)`
this just makes a data frame that is one row long but equal to the final row of the iterative dataframe

i have also tried:
`Storage_Df.iloc[i-1] = Iterating_Df.iloc[-1]`
but this throws a "IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds" error

where i is the currently length of the iterating `Df`.

i appreciate any help, if you need more info just let me know

EDit:
Here is a simplified version of the code. basically what i am trying to do is take historical stock data and split it into daily , weekly and monthly data (for open, high, low and close of the share price). the issue i am facing is if i dont make the calculation iterate row by row and instead feed the entire datasheet the program will use an entire month of data when analyzing the share on say the 5th of the month. this essentially gives my program the ability to see into the future giving me biased trading results. to correct this i am trying to feed the data into the program row by row and harvest the last line thus preserving the analysis for the day.

```
def stock_Data():
for i in range(1, len(df) + 8):
    # this pulls in the data from a csv
    dr = pd.read_csv(stock, nrows=i, names=["Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Null"])
    dr = dr.drop(columns=["Null"])
    #this drops dates i dont want
    dr = dr[dr.Date != 20191225]
    dr = dr[dr.Date != 20191226]
    dr = dr[dr.Date != 20200101]
    dr = dr[dr.Date != 20200127]
    dr = dr[dr.Date != 20200410]
    dr = dr[dr.Date != 20200413]
    dr = dr[dr.Date != 20200608]

    dr = dr.reset_index(drop=True)
    #this converts the date into date-time format
    dr['Date'] = dr.Date.astype(str)
    dr['Date1'] = dr['Date'].str[:4] + "-"
    dr['Date2'] = dr['Date'].str[4:6] + "-"
    dr['Date3'] = dr['Date'].str[6:]
    dr['Date'] = dr['Date1'] + dr['Date2'] + dr['Date3']
    dr['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dr['Date'])
    dr = dr.drop(columns=["Date1", "Date2", "Date3"])

    #this creates dataframes for the weekly and monthly data
    dr['Week_Number'] = dr['Date'].dt.week
    dr['Month_Number'] = dr['Date'].dt.month
    dr['Year'] = dr['Date'].dt.year
    dr2 = dr.groupby(['Year', 'Week_Number'], as_index=False).agg({'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last', 'Volume': 'sum'})

    dr3 = dr.groupby(['Year', 'Month_Number'], as_index=False).agg({'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last', 'Volume': 'sum'})

    #this is a set of sample calculations
    dr['Change'] = (dr['Close'] - dr['Close'].shift(1)) / dr['Close'].shift(1)
    dr2['Change'] = (dr2['Close'] - dr2['Close'].shift(1)) / dr2['Close'].shift(1)
    dr3['Change'] = (dr3['Close'] - dr3['Close'].shift(1)) / dr3['Close'].shift(1)

    dr['Daily_Final'] = pd.np.where(dr['Change'] >= 0.1 , 1, 0)
    dr2['Weekly_Final'] = pd.np.where(dr2['Change'] >= 0.5 , 1, 0)
    dr3['Monthly_Final'] = pd.np.where(dr3['Change'] >= 0.75, 1, 0)

    #this brings the daily, weekly and monthly back onto a single DF so it can be used in conjunction with each other

    dr['Week_ID'] = pd.np.where(dr['Year'] == 2018, dr['Week_Number'], pd.np.where(dr['Year'] == 2019, pd.np.where(
        ((dr['Week_Number'] == 1) & (dr['Month_Number'] == 12)), dr['Week_Number'] + 2000, dr['Week_Number'] + 1000),
                                                                                   dr['Week_Number'] + 2000))
    dr['Month_ID'] = pd.np.where(dr['Year'] == 2018, dr['Month_Number'],
                                 pd.np.where(dr['Year'] == 2019, dr['Month_Number'] + 1000, dr['Month_Number'] + 2000))

    dr2['Week_ID'] = pd.np.where(dr2['Year'] == 2018, dr2['Week_Number'],
                                 pd.np.where(dr2['Year'] == 2019, dr2['Week_Number'] + 1000, dr2['Week_Number'] + 2000))
    Iterating_DF = pd.merge(left=dr, right=dr2[['Week_ID', 'Weekly_Final']], how="inner", on="Week_ID")
    dr3['Month_ID'] = pd.np.where(dr3['Year'] == 2018, dr3['Month_Number'],
                                  pd.np.where(dr3['Year'] == 2019, dr3['Month_Number'] + 1000,
                                              dr3['Month_Number'] + 2000))

    Iterating_DF = pd.merge(left=Iterating_DF, right=dr3[['Month_ID', 'Monthly_Final']], how="inner", on="Month_ID")
    Iterating_DF['Final_Trend'] = pd.np.where(
        (Iterating_DF['Daily_Final'] + Iterating_DF['Weekly_Final'] + Iterating_DF['Monthly_Final']) >= 2, 1, 0)

    #this is my attempt to harvest the last row of the dataframe
    Storage_Df = pd.DataFrame()
    Storage_Df = Storage_Df.append(Iterating_Df.iloc[-1], ignore_index = True)
return (Storage_Df['Final_Trend'])
```

Comment: can you add a few rows of your input data and what you're expecting ?

Comment: Defining your Storage_Df before the for loop might help. Now, in each iteration, you create a new Storage_Df

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following.To get the last row you can use dataframe.tail()

```
storage_df=pd.DataFrame()
last_row=Iterating_df.tail(1)
storage_df=storage_df.append(last_row,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: This resulted in the same output as the df.append attempt i had tried. 
i will add more info

Comment: I think so when  without loop it should work.. for your case may be add a loop to iterate over your iterating df. so that it reads the value of last row in all the iterations.